# What is the probability space for continuous random variables? (hopefully without too much measure theory)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Random variables are functions mapping from probability space / experiments to numbers.
$$
X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$

In the discrete case, say the experiment is rolling a 6-sided die, I know clearly what the event space is.

- For continuous random variables, say a Gaussian, or an Exponential distribution, what is their underlying event space? Or do they share the same event space?
- When we talk about linearity of expectation, a classic proof is roughly $\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \int_{\omega} [X(\omega) + Y(\omega)] d{\omega} = \int_{\omega} X(\omega) d{\omega} + \int_{\omega} Y(\omega) d{\omega} = \mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[Y]  $. For this to work out, the two random variables must share the event space. How would this work for continuous random variables?
- Some continuous random variables, e.g. Exponential, only take positive values. In this case does it still share the same event space as Gaussian, whose range is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It sounds like you might be conflating a probability *distribution* with a random variable. The shared probability space for a pair of real-valued random variables could be $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$. The point of having a shared probability space is that it allows us to model non-independent variables.

Answer (score 1):

There is never an unique way do define the probability space in which a random variable is defined, not even for the discrete case.

One possible choice is to take $\Omega=[0,1]$, the sigma-algebra of Borel and the Lebesgue measure. Then, if $F_X$ is the desired cdf for $X$, we can define

$$X(\omega)=\inf\{x \in \mathbb{R}; F_X(x) \ge \omega \}.$$

A litte effort wil show that $X$ has cdf $F_x$.

Things will become a little more complicated if we need to define more than one random variable in the same space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest a conceptual shift in your thinking. As the other answer mentions, if you want to be specific, you can take $\left([0, 1], \mathcal B\left([0, 1]\right)\right)$ as your measurable space, no matter what kind of random variable you want to think about. (If you want to read more about this, check out Theorem 1.104 in Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course, 3rd Edition, by Klenke.)

Without getting into too much measure theory, the sophisticated perspective makes the CDF the central object, which bypasses all the seeming distinction between discrete and continuous random variables. The CDF uniquely identifies a random variable, continuous, discrete, or something else. All random variables have a CDF.

Lastly, regarding linearity of expectation, this is a property of the measure-theoretic integral, so it requires that the two random variables share the same probability space for their domain (assuming they are both real-valued). This has nothing to do with whether either of them is discrete, continuous, or something else.

Comment: So are you saying that all random variables (discrete, continuous) can share the same event space?


And that it makes sense to talk about $\mathbb{E}(X + Y)$ even if $X$ is discrete, e.g. a Bernoulli r.v, whereas $Y$ is a Gaussian?

Comment: @photoid Yes, we can always construct a probability space where all the r.v.'s of our interest are defined.

Comment: @photoid I am pretty sure the *event space* $\Omega$ is not the issue. I believe the subtlety will lie in the fact that $X$ and $Y$ will each have different pushforward measures, call them $\mathbb P_X$ and $\mathbb P_Y$. The expectation of $X + Y$ will need to be taken with respect to one measure. Admittedly I am not precisely sure how this is resolved, but you wanted to avoid measure theory, so...

Comment: Thank you both for the help! Do u have a recommended reading suggestion? I looked at Klenke just now but it seems a little too daunting.

Comment: @photoid I mean, it depends if you want to deal with the measure theory or not. I don't think you will understand these issues if you insist on avoiding the measure theory. I am looking at the new book by Le Gall; it's not as comprehensive as Klenke, but it might be a little bit easier and more intutive.

Comment: @Novice thanks for the pointer to Le Gall. It does look like a more approachable place to start.